# Trigger.new is null in before insert and before update

Tags: apex, trigger

I have scenario where i need to calculate two fields Data_quality_score and Data_quality_desc on account object when a new account is created or updated based on other field values.
I have the following trigger handler class. In which i have created one method called PopulateDataQualityScoreFields to calculate the data quality score field values before saving the record.

```
public class AccountTriggerHandler extends TriggerFrameWork {
    private List<Account> newAccountList;
    private Map<Id, Account> oldAccountMap;

    public AccountTriggerHandler() {
        this.newAccountList = (List<Account>) Trigger.new;
        this.oldAccountMap = (Map<Id,Account>) Trigger.oldmap; 
    }
    public override void beforeInsert() {
        for(Account account : newAccountList) {
            if(account.Firm_Revenue_Last_Known__c != null) {
                account.Firm_Revenue__c = account.Firm_Revenue_Last_Known__c;
            }
            if(account.Firm_Revenue_Last_Known__c == null && account.Firm_Revenue_2_Years_Ago__c != null) {
                account.Firm_Revenue__c = account.Firm_Revenue_2_Years_Ago__c;
            }
            if(account.Firm_Revenue_Last_Known__c == null && account.Firm_Revenue_2_Years_Ago__c == null
                    && account.Firm_Revenue_3_Years_Ago__c != null) {
                account.Firm_Revenue__c = account.Firm_Revenue_3_Years_Ago__c;
            }
            if(account.Lead_Type__c == 'Household') {
                account.recordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('Household').getRecordTypeId();
            }
            if(account.Lead_Type__c == 'Firm') {
                account.recordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('Firm').getRecordTypeId();
            }
        }
        PopulateDataQualityScoreFields();
    }
    public override void beforeUpdate() {
        for(Account account : newAccountList) {
            if(account.Firm_Revenue_Last_Known__c != null && account.Firm_Revenue_Last_Known__c != oldAccountMap.get(account.Id).Firm_Revenue_Last_Known__c) {
                account.Firm_Revenue__c = account.Firm_Revenue_Last_Known__c;
            }
            if(account.Firm_Revenue_Last_Known__c == null && account.Firm_Revenue_2_Years_Ago__c != null
                    && account.Firm_Revenue_2_Years_Ago__c != oldAccountMap.get(account.Id).Firm_Revenue_2_Years_Ago__c) {
                account.Firm_Revenue__c = account.Firm_Revenue_2_Years_Ago__c;
            }
            if(account.Firm_Revenue_Last_Known__c == null && account.Firm_Revenue_2_Years_Ago__c == null
                    && account.Firm_Revenue_3_Years_Ago__c != null
                    && account.Firm_Revenue_3_Years_Ago__c != oldAccountMap.get(account.Id).Firm_Revenue_3_Years_Ago__c) {
                account.Firm_Revenue__c = account.Firm_Revenue_3_Years_Ago__c;
            }
        }
        PopulateDataQualityScoreFields();
    }

 public void PopulateDataQualityScoreFields( )
   {
    String DQDescription;
    Integer DQScore;
    for(Account account : newAccountList) {
    if (account.Lead_Type__c == 'Firm') {
        if(account.Data_Quality_Score__c <> 100){
          DQDescription = 'Missing: ';
          if(account.Owner.Profile.Name == null || account.Owner.Profile.Name == 'Integration Profile'){
             DQDescription = DQDescription + 'Owner,';
             DQScore = DQScore + 10;
          }
          if(account.AuMine_External_Id__c <> null && (account.Regional_Firms_Broker__c == null ||
             account.Regional_Firms_Broker__c == 'Integration Profile')){
             DQDescription = DQDescription + 'RF Broker';
             DQScore = DQScore + 5;
          } 
          if(account.Related_Contacts__c == null || account.isVictim__c == True){
            DQDescription = DQDescription + 'Contact, ';
            DQScore = DQScore + 15;
          }
          if(account.Phone_MDM__c == null || account.Phone_MDM__c.length() !=10){
            DQDescription = DQDescription + 'Phone, ';
            DQScore = DQScore + 15;
          } 
          if(account.Firm_Revenue__c == null || account.Firm_Revenue__c == 0){
            DQDescription = DQDescription + 'Firm Revenue, ';
            DQScore = DQScore + 15;
          } 
          if(account.AuMine_External_Id__c <> null && account.Tax_ID__c == null){
             DQDescription = DQDescription + 'Tax ID, ';
             DQScore = DQScore + 5;
          }
          if(account.hasBusinessAddress__c == null || account.hasBusinessAddress__c == 0){
            DQDescription = DQDescription + 'Biz Address,';
            DQScore = DQScore + 15;
          } 
          if(account.Last_Known_PL_Expiration_Date__c == null){
            DQDescription = DQDescription + 'Last Known PL Expiration Date, ';
            DQScore = DQScore + 10;
          }
          if(account.Missing_Renewal_Opportunities__c > 0){
            DQDescription = DQDescription + account.Missing_Renewal_Opportunities__c + 'Renewal Opportunity';
            DQScore = DQScore + 10;
          }
          account.Data_Quality_Score__c = DQScore ; 
          account.Data_Quality_Description__c = DQDescription;
                                                    
       }
    } 
   } 
      
   } 
    
}
```

Trigger

```
trigger AccountUpdatedTrigger on Account (before insert, before update, after update, after insert) {
    if(Trigger_Settings__c.getAll().get('AccountUpdatedTrigger') != null && Trigger_Settings__c.getAll().get('AccountUpdatedTrigger').Active__c) {
        new AccountTriggerHandler().run();
    }
```

Debug Log

```
12:50:12.368 (1455820914)|METHOD_ENTRY|[50]|01p8A000009RPz6|AccountTriggerHandler.beforeUpdate()
12:50:12.368 (1455862362)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[92]|List<Account>.iterator()
12:50:12.368 (1455878348)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[92]|List<Account>.iterator()
12:50:12.368 (1455892413)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[92]|system.ListIterator.hasNext()
12:50:12.368 (1455905820)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[92]|system.ListIterator.hasNext()
12:50:12.368 (1455993676)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[92]|system.ListIterator.hasNext()
12:50:12.368 (1456002205)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[92]|system.ListIterator.hasNext()
12:50:12.368 (1456047660)|METHOD_ENTRY|[106]|01p8A000009RPz6|AccountTriggerHandler.PopulateDataQualityScoreFields(List<Account>)
12:50:12.368 (1456072447)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[126]|List<Account>.iterator()
12:50:12.368 (1456084616)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[126]|List<Account>.iterator()
12:50:12.368 (1456090534)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[126]|system.ListIterator.hasNext()
12:50:12.368 (1456097069)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[126]|system.ListIterator.hasNext()
12:50:12.368 (1456130105)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[126]|system.ListIterator.hasNext()
12:50:12.368 (1456140882)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[126]|system.ListIterator.hasNext()
12:50:12.368 (1456151019)|METHOD_EXIT|[106]|01p8A000009RPz6|AccountTriggerHandler.PopulateDataQualityScoreFields(List<Account>)
12:50:12.368 (1456159533)|METHOD_EXIT|[50]|01p8A000009RPz6|AccountTriggerHandler.beforeUpdate()
12:50:12.368 (1456166890)|METHOD_EXIT|[13]|01p8A000009Bwnu|TriggerFrameWork.run()
```

But it is not updating. The list newAccountList doesnt have any value in the PopulateDataQualityScoreFields method in the debug log. So the loop exits without calculating. Whats wrong in the code ? Can anybody help with this ?

I have tried sending trigger.new as a parameter to the method `PopulateDataQualityScoreFields(List<Account>)`. That time also `trigger.new` is null.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are misinterpreting the debug log

The `system.listIterator.hasNext()` entries are the `for` loop executing over the values in `newAccountList`

Instead, your problem may be on this line:

```
if(account.Owner.Profile.Name == null || account.Owner.Profile.Name == 'Integration Profile'){
```

or possibly that the triggered account data doesn't meet any of the other if conditions in `PopulateDataQualityScoreFields` - like `Lead_Type__c` is not `Firm`

When a trigger starts, lookup record values are not in the trigger's context. They need to be queried for (bulkified of course). Thus `account.Owner.Profile.Name` will not have a value